# how to put hint to edittext

Tags: android

I have two edittext input box. First one is for username and the second one is for password. I want put hint on the inputbox. I have wrote hint with settex() method. In addition, I have wrote

```
      in onclick(view v) 

           caseR.id.editText_1:
                 text1.setText("");  
                  break;

      in oncreate 

            text1 = findViewById(R.id.editText_1);
            text1.setText("username");
```

whenever I have click on the input box, hint should dissappear. But, hint is not dissappeared. Now, is the way I am doing wrong? Or I have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
text1.setHint("MyHintString");
```

instead. [`setHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) provides the hint that disappears when the user types something. You can also use a String resource ID or an xml based approach, but in your case, using the String method will suffice.

Only use `setText()` when you want to put text in the EditText that the user can modify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `editTextExample.setHint("example")` to achieve what you want.

OR, in XML, add this to your EditText: `android:hint="example"`

Answer (score 1):

the correct way to do this is to use [`setHint(int resource)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) with a [string resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) containing your hint string.

so your `onCreate` should have : `text1.setHint(R.String.yourhint);`

and your res->values->strings.xml file should contain

```
<string name="yourhint">This Hint Will Disappear</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`setHint(String hint)`** to specify the hint in an EditText.

```
text1.setHint("This is the hint...");
```

Or, in your XML layout file, you can use the attribute **`android:hint="This is the Hint"`** for the corresponding EditText.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it in xml file of the activity you can do it like this too.

in your xml file `android:hint="@string/yourhint"`

and your res->values->strings.xml file should contain

```
<string name="yourhint">This Hint Will Disappear</string>
```